# How to use "v-if" in Vue.js to render a <span> only if parent div has a specific property?

Tags: html, vue.js

What I'm trying to do is make it so that `<span v-if="spinnerToggle && command-id=='updateAllExternalReferences'">Spin</span>` only renders when `spinnerToggle` has a value of `true` **and** the parent div has a `command-id` property of `updateAllExternalReferences`.

I've been able to get this to work using only the `spinnerToggle` conditional, but adding the `command-id` one causes it to give me the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Does `v-if` not support conditionals that reference properties in the parent div? If so, how should I implement this sort of functionality? Below you'll find the parent div and the respective `<span>`.

```
<div class="tool is-activatable"
      v-if="config.isVisibleToUser"
      @click="dispatch"
      :class="[config.cssClass, {'is-active': active, 'is-highlighted': highlight, 'is-button': !context.reordering}]"
      :command-id="config.command"
      :context-menu-name="contextMenu.name"
      :context-menu-details="contextMenu.contextMenuDetails"
      :data-id="config.id"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :data-placement="inMenu ? 'right-top' : config.tooltipPosition || 'bottom'"
      :data-original-title="(config.tooltipKey || config.tooltip || config.toolName) | i18next"
      :data-expanded-content="(config.expandedTooltipKey || config.expandedTooltip) | i18next" data-html="true"
      :data-expand-delay="inMenu ? 0 : config.expandDelay > -1 ? config.expandDelay : 2000"
      :data-trigger="config.tooltipTrigger"
      :tooltip-dynamic-snippet-id="dynamicSnippetId">

  <img v-if="!hasIcon && config.img" :src="config.img" />
  <ToolIcon v-if="hasIcon" :icon="config.icon" :iconUri="config.iconUri" :initials="config.iconInitials"
            :awaitingData="false" :updateAvailable="config.isNewerVersionAvailable"/>
  <span v-if="spinnerToggle && command-id=='updateAllExternalReferences'">Spin</span>

  <span class="tool-label" :class="{'hide-in-toolbar': !shouldShowLabel}">
    {{ (config.toolDisplayName || config.toolName) | i18next }}
  </span>
  <ShortcutKeys v-if="inMenu" :shortcut="shortcut" />
  <div v-if="context.reordering" class="drag-handle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly reference the attribute from the parent `<div>` but you can reference the same data that was used to populate it:

```html
<span v-if="spinnerToggle && config.command === 'updateAllExternalReferences'">Spin</span>
```

If the `command-id` expression were more complicated you could refactor to use a computed property rather than duplicating the same logic in both places.